# Run a Python script on S3 Files

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3

**I want to run a python script on my entire S3 Bucket.** 
The script takes the files and inserts them into a csv file.

> how can I run on the S3 files like a local script does?
>   using "python https://s3url/" doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use boto3 to get the list of all the files in s3 bucket:

```
import boto3

bucketName = "Your S3 BucketName"

# Create an S3 client
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

for key in s3.list_objects(Bucket=bucketName)['Contents']: 
    print(key['Key'])
```

Comment: But I want to run a script on all files and to add them into one csv file, I don't need to list them

Comment: so you want to insert the name of files in csv?

Comment: No, I want to parse JSONS which are in the S3 into a csv

Comment: so you want to read the file and then insert file data into csv?

Comment: Yes, I need to process them into one csv

Answer (score 0):

A good idea would be to use [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html). Here is a [simple guide](https://realpython.com/python-boto3-aws-s3/) on how to use the module